# Highchart auto pageup the browser when data is updated

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I found the annoying problem that when my highchart is updated, my browser will pageup automatically. I already search for the solution ([Check this link](https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/pie-chart-makes-page-scroll-all-the-way-up-t13451/)) and they explain that the cause is about calling `new chart`, but in my code I don't use that.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="gp_power">
        <div id="graph_power"></div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 function read(){
  $.post("graph_power.php", 
  function(data, status){
  if(status == 'success'){

      cur_date = (data.cur_date.join(','));
      pow_dat_0000 = Number(data.pow_dat_0000.join(','));

      graph_power(cur_date, pow_dat_0000);
  }
  });
 };
 read();
  setInterval(function() {
    if(new Date().getMinutes() % 1 == 0){
      if(new Date().getSeconds() == 0){
       read();
      }
    }
  }, 100)

function graph_power(cur_date, pow_dat_0000) {
        $('#graph_power').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80]
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    colorByPoint: true
                }
            },
            colors: [
                '#e74c3c',
                '#3498db',

            ],
            title: {
                text: 'Power Consumption of Today ' +'[ '+ '<b>' + cur_date + '</b>' + ' ]'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['00:00','00:30'],
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '9px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Power (watt)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                        'Power: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +
                        ' watt';
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Watts',
                data: [pow_dat_0000, pow_dat_0030],

                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: -90,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                    x: 4,
                    y: 10,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '0px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    };
});
```

Please help me solve this problem. Thank you :)

Comment: You kind of use new ```Highcharts.Chart```, look at source code, where highcharts registers as a jQuery plugin.
http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart.update method redraws chart, so your chart disappears for a split of second.

Just set your container height with CSS to specific value.

[EDIT]
I also noticed, that your code recreates whole chart every time you get a new data, this approach is terrible. I made an example which shows how you should update your data:

```
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Live Bitcoin Price'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Price (USD)'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Live Bitcoint Price [USD]',
    data: []
  }]
}
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)

// Data
const getData = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    window.fetch('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd').then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    }).then((data) => {
      chart.series[0].addPoint({ x: data.timestamp * 1000, y: Number(data.ticker.price) })
    })
  }, 3000)
}
getData()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpfkx91w/

Comment: "Just set your container height with CSS to specific value." This is simple but can solve the problem. Thank you :)